# Why this simple example does not work any more?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Since today, this example does not work:

```
let app;

const options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    accessToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ1OXc4b2NYc3Y3dm96Rm9PQWVjakhGckZwRmN6cmZBbiIsImV4cCI6MTU0MTE5MTk2NSwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiLCJidWNrZXQ6cmVhZCIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYWNjb3VudDpyZWFkIiwiYWNjb3VudDp3cml0ZSJdLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJTeDBQN3BINFluQ01mZnVOUnJYYTR0SHRXa3dka2VqZm9EMWxFNkdiODB2NEpmNVZvd2RLeGVPNXc2V3laSXpwIn0.R8hURNQ1XHaZF0tFmf8e58lDeWUp6s_fw4Ry3Q3rT6k'
};
const urn = 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2FsYV9idWNrZXQvZHdnMS5kd2c=';

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    app = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('viewer');
    app.registerViewer(app.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess() {
    const viewables = app.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
    app.selectItem(viewables[0].data);
  }
  function onDocumentLoadFailure() {}
  app.loadDocument('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

it was working for the past few days, but now it is giving me 404 error (not found). Why it does not work, please?

Comment: Please include your code in your question (not as a link but actual code). Make sure it's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Trying to cheat the warnings by including links in the comments will only get your question closed.

Comment: OK I did, but on jsfiddle is complete example worked before few days. I'm not sure does code above is enough or I need to post whole code?

Comment: Please? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the same code on my side, it works as the following picture, could you please make sure your token is valid and check again? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You have right, code is here. Problem was somewhere in preparing steps. When I uploaded file manually, it works.